# Teradata SQL Syntax - Common Table Expressions

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, teradata, recursive-query

When using multiple CTE's in MSSQL 2008, I normally separate them with a comma.

But when I try this in a Teradata environment, I get an error with the syntax.

Works in MS SQL:

```
WITH CTE1 AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 Name FROM Sales.Store)
,CTE2 AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 ProductNumber, Name FROM Production.Product)
,CTE3 AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 Name FROM Person.ContactType)
SELECT * FROM CTE1,CTE2,CTE3
```

Now, attempting to put into Teradata syntax:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE1 (Name) AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 Name FROM Sales.Store)
,RECURSIVE CTE2 (ProductNumber, Name) AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 ProductNumber, Name FROM Production.Product)
,RECURSIVE CTE3 (Name) AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 Name FROM Person.ContactType)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE1,CTE2,CTE3
```

> Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited
>   identifier between ',' and the 'RECURSIVE' keyword.

2nd attempt (without using RECURSIVE multiple times)

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE1 (Name) AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 Name FROM Sales.Store)
,CTE2 (ProductNumber, Name) AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 ProductNumber, Name FROM Production.Product)
,CTE3 (Name) AS 
(SELECT TOP 2 Name FROM Person.ContactType)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE1,CTE2,CTE3
```

> *Multiple WITH definitions are not supported.*

Comment: The 2nd attempt is the correct ANSI SQL syntax, but apparently teradata does not support this (at least that's how I would interpret the error message "*not supported*")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple CTEs are supported on version 14.0 of Teradata. You can download TD v14 for VMware from the Teradata Developer Network web site and test it out.