# multiple common table expressions in teradata

Tags: teradata

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661416/teradata-sql-syntax-common-table-expressions) teradata v14.0 supports multiple common table expressions. So the simplified script as follows:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT       
                X                                       
        FROM SomeTable
)
,CTE2 AS
(
        SELECT top 10 X FROM CTE1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2
```

should work. Unfortunately, I get:

```
Object 'CTE1' does not exist.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Using-WITH-Statement-Modifier-instead-of-Temp-Tables/m-p/62317

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at this. One suggestion here is to put the ctes in reverse order (will try tomorrow). However, the user also points out that this not work. So not sure if you comment is useful at the mo.

Comment: Multiple CTEs in Teradata are so screwy, I almost never think it's worth the headache to get it working right.  I'd just use volatile tables. I've never compared the explain plans of the two options, but I'd think the performance would be similar.

Comment: @Andrew - would you be so kind and transform the question's cte code into volatile table code? This would be an acceptable answer.